# Понять какой объект вызвал событие

Tags: jquery, события

Все тривиально. Есть форма и 2 кнопки, которые могут её сабмитить.
Пусть так:

```
<form>
...
<input type=submit name=name1 ...>
<input type=submit name=name2 ...>
</form>
```

обработчик:

```
$('#searchForm').bind( 'submit', function() {
                bx_loading('searchForm', true);
                 var sQuery = $('input', '#searchForm').serialize();
                 $.post('searchKeywordContent.php', sQuery, function(data) {

                         $('#searchArea').html(data);
                         bx_loading('searchForm', false);
                    }
                );
            return false;
          }
         );
```

Как внутри обработчика понять какая кнопка вызвала событие?

Comment: + additional question:

В jQuery есть аналог функции php var_dump()?

Comment: если сабмитеть форму по клику, то `this` обработчика будет ссылаться на кликнутую кнопку, вот только зачем вам 2 сабмита я не могу понять

Comment: Понимать это не нужно =\
А вот форму по onclick отправлять это интересно зачем. А если он(юзверь) по Enter"у будет форму отправлять? Ещё и это отдельно обрабатывать? Бредово как-то.

Comment: Попробуйте навешать обработчик клика на сами кнопки и при клике вызывать сабмит формы. Тогда можно определить нажатую кнопку передав в обработчик переменную e например. Тогда e.target будет ссылаться на нажатую кнопку.

Comment: Пол поводу var_dump http://hashcode.ru/questions/185057/эквивалент-var_dump-в-javascript

Comment: submit событие вызывается ФОРМОЙ а не кнопкой, по этому хоть какую жмите определить будет не возможно. Если уж очень надо 2 кнокпи поставить и определить какая именно нажата используйте 2 обычные button. 1 форма 1 кнопка submit должно быть IMHO

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17805011/815386

вот реализация:

http://jsfiddle.net/wC759/

Answer (score 2):

```
function Название функции([Объект event]) {
// ...
}
```

Элемент, вызвавший событие, доступен внутри функции через указатель `this`. Обратите внимание на то, что указатель `this` ссылается на элемент объектной модели документа, а не на элемент коллекции `jQuery`. Если в параметре Объект event указана переменная, то через нее можно обратиться к свойствам объекта `event`. Напишем обработчик щелчка мыши для двух элементов сразу. При нажатии выведем название тега в элементе с идентификатором `divl`.

```
$("р, div").click(function(е)   { 
       $("#divl")
.append("Элемент " + e.srcElement.tagName + "<br>");
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это здорово, конечно. Но у меня $('#searchForm').bind( 'submit', function(e) {
alert(e.srcElement.tagName);
....

Всегда выкинет "FORM". Т.к. я сабмит ловлю. Вопрос в том, можно ли понять кто вызвал этот сабмит?

Comment: с чего вдруг FORM выкинет?

Comment: Ну вот так.. Видимо потому что слушается событие submit для #searchForm (у меня это <form...>). то есть он возвращает элемент, который вызывает fire события, а не который провоцирует вызов этого fire.

Comment: аа понял) а если ловть событе onClick? или вам етот вариант неподходит?

Comment: Не подходит. Сделал вот как вообщем:

К форме добавил скрытое поле и обрабатываю onclick для кнопок. Если 1я, то одно значение скрытой переменной на сервер летит, ну и... дальше понятно.

Если по Enter'y форму отправляют, то значение по умолчанию - будто 1ю кнопку нажали. Ничего лучше мой мозг не выдал.

Comment: а ето еще зачем? на сервере вы и так можете узнать какую кнопку нажали по содержимому массива $_GET или $_POST - в зависимости от того каким методом идет отправка. Грубо говоря если нажата кнопка с name=name2 - и при отправке GET - на сервере проверяете существование  переменной $_GET['name2'], аналогично с POST

Comment: Так бы и сделал, если б было дозволено. Приходится работать в "странном" окружении, где нет доступа к глобальным массивам.

Comment: сочувствую

Answer (score 2):

Может как-нибудь так:

```
<form action="">
    <input type="submit" name="opa1">
    <input type="submit" name="opa2">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        submitForm();

        // console.log($(this).attr('name'));
    });

    $('form').on('submit', submitForm);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

По мотивам [ответа на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17805011/815386)

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e) {
    var $btn = $(document.activeElement,this);
    if ($btn.is('button, input[type="submit"], input[type="image"]') && $btn.is('[name]'))
    {console.log($btn);}
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wC759/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    //alert(e.relatedTarget.name);//не работает в Chrome и FF
    alert($(document.activeElement,this)[0].name); 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: забудьте вы уже про live.

Comment: Так и знал что к live будут придираться :) Можно и без него обойтись не спорю, смотрите код в нутрии функции который решает проблему ТС.

Comment: не работает же в таком виде relatedTarget (как минимум в chrome и ff 24.2.0) http://jsfiddle.net/B4Zwm/1/

ну и цитата с [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.relatedTarget):

> Only MouseEvents have this property, and its value makes sense only for certain MouseEvents:

Comment: Действительно не работает в chrome, спасибо. Вчера проверял только в Опере где все отлично срабатывало.

Comment: так сработает не только на кнопки но и на `<input type="text">`

Comment: Если имеете ввиду что сработает по нажатию Enter'а когда фокус ввода находится в текстовом поле то в моем случае это не страшно. Мне главное определить, когда конкретно нажали на submit с name="delete"

if($(document.activeElement,this)[0].name === 'delete')
{
   delete(...);
}

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
        <input class="submit-1" type="submit" value="Button 1"/>
        <input class="submit-2" type="submit" value="Button 2"/>
    </form>
```

JS:

```
$('#form :submit').on('click', function (e) {
    if($(e.target).is('.submit-1')) {
        console.log('click submit 1');
    } else {
        console.log('click submit 2');
    }
});
```

При проверке, что все работает как надо, первой строчкой в обработчике напишете e.preventDefault(), это остановит действия по умолчанию, то есть отправку формы.

Answer (score 0):

Простейший способ получить объект,вызвавший событие:

```
$('#youForm').on('submit', function() { $(this).css('color', '#fff'); });
```

Comment: автор вопросa хочет получить кнопку, а в твоем пример `this` - это форма с Id=youForm

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();     

    var target= e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget;

    console.log(target);

});
```